# More precision in functions for gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot this function with gnuplot

[image]

but when I try to do it a find this `Warning: empty y range [1:1], adjusting to [0.99:1.01]`. I think that it should be a precision problem. I can plot it perfectly in another programs, but I would like to know why I can not plot it with gnuplot and how to fix it

Edit:

The command that I'm using is

`f(x)=(1-(sinh(1/x))**(-4))**(1/8)`

`plot [0.01:1.131] f(x)`

Comment: Please show the command you used in gnuplot.  Also show what x range you tried to plot - note that sinh(1/x) blows up for x near zero.

Comment: I have edited the question with this information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. That equation as written does not match the one you showed. Is the exponent supposed to be 4 or -4?
2. Gnuplot uses integer arithmetic, so (1/8) evaluates to 0.   Use either (1./8.) or (.125)

Possible correction (depending on what is the correct exponent):

```
f(x) = (1. - (sinh(1/x)**(-4)))**(1./8.)
set xrange [0.01 : 1.131]
plot f(x)
```

[image]

Comment: You are right, I put -4 in the exponent. I already change it. The answer to my problem is  that gnuplot use integer arithmetic, like you said. Thank you